# Find different strings and return containing tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Say I have the following HTML:

```
<p>
If everybody minded their own business, the world would go around a great deal faster than it does.
</p>

<p>
Who in the world am I? Ah, that's the great puzzle.
</p>
```

I would like to be able to find all Tags that contain ALL of the keywords that I'm looking for. E.g. (example 2 and 3 won't work):

```
>>> len(soup.find_all(text="world"))
2

>>> len(soup.find_all(text="world puzzle"))
1

>>> len(soup.find_all(text="world puzzle book"))
0
```

I've been trying to come up with a regular expression that allows me to search for all keywords, but it seems ANDing is impossible (only ORing).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What I meant to say is that I cannot find a way to use a regular expression to find all of a set of keywords (book AND world AND puzzle) in a string. Instead only ('book|world|puzzle') - ORing - seems to be feasible. (As you might have gathered, I still haven't fully gotten my head around regular expressions).

Comment: Ohhh I see. I am unfamiliar with python and assume they dont have && like java?

Comment: `re.compile(r'world.+puzzle.+book.+')` would require all of them, in order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do a complex match like this is to [write a function that performs the match](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function), and pass in the function as the value for the `text` argument.

```
def must_contain_all(*strings):                                                 
    def must_contain(markup):                                                   
        return markup is not None and all(s in markup for s in strings)         
    return must_contain
```

Now you can get the strings that match:

```
print soup.find_all(text=must_contain_all("world", "puzzle"))
# [u"\nWho in the world am I? Ah, that's the great puzzle.\n"]
```

To get the tags containing the strings, use the .parent operator:

```
print [text.parent for text in soup.find_all(text=must_contain_all("world", "puzzle"))]
# [<p>Who in the world am I? Ah, that's the great puzzle.</p>]
```

Comment: What... I never thought of passing extra arguments to the function that performs the match.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) instead of BeautifulSoup.
lxml allows you to find elements by XPaths:

With this boiler-plate setup:

```
import lxml.html as LH
import re

html = """
<p>
If everybody minded their own business, the world would go around a great deal faster than it does.
</p>

<p>
Who in the world am I? Ah, that's the great puzzle.
</p>
"""

doc = LH.fromstring(html)
```

This finds the text in all `<p>` tags which contains the string `world`:

```
print(doc.xpath('//p[contains(text(),"world")]/text()'))
['\nIf everybody minded their own business, the world would go around a great deal faster than it does.\n', "\nWho in the world am I? Ah, that's the great puzzle.\n"]
```

And this finds all the text in all `<p>` tags which contains `world` and `puzzle`:

```
print(doc.xpath('//p[contains(text(),"world") and contains(text(),"puzzle")]/text()'))
["\nWho in the world am I? Ah, that's the great puzzle.\n"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most efficient method, but you could try set intersections:

```
len(set(soup.find_all(text="world")
    & set(soup.find_all(text="book")
    & set(soup.find_all(text="puzzle")))
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a skeleton (and I'm using lxml not BeautifulSoup, but you can adapt around that using soup.findAll):

```
html = """
<p>
If everybody minded their own business, the world would go around a great deal faster than it does.
</p>

<p>
Who in the world am I? Ah, that's the great puzzle.
</p>
"""

import lxml.html
import re

fragment = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
d = dict(
    (node, set(re.findall(r'\S+', node.text_content())))
    for node in fragment.xpath('//p'))

for node, it in d.iteritems():
    # then use set logic to go from here...
```